# Is a GeoDjango MultiPolygonField supposed to accept a Polygon geometry?

Tags: django, geodjango, geos

When I try to set a `Polygon` on a `MultiPolygonField` the following exception is raised:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mattrowbum/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/proxy.py", line 75, in __set__
    instance.__class__.__name__, gtype, type(value)))
TypeError: Cannot set Location SpatialProxy (MULTIPOLYGON) with value of type: <class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.polygon.Polygon'>
```

That would be understandable, except that a note in the [GeoDjango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#gdal-interface) states:

> ...a GeoDjango MultiPolygonField will accept a Polygon geometry.

I've had a look at the [source of proxy.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/gis/db/models/proxy.py#L64), and it is checking whether the value (a `Polygon`) is an instance of the relevant geometry class (a `MultiPolygon`). I've tried doing this check manually which confirms that a `Polygon` does not inherit from `MultiPolygon`:

```sh
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import MultiPolygon, Polygon
>>> ext_coords = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0))
>>> int_coords = ((0.4, 0.4), (0.4, 0.6), (0.6, 0.6), (0.6, 0.4), (0.4, 0.4))
>>> poly = Polygon(ext_coords, int_coords)
>>> isinstance(poly, Polygon)
True
>>> isinstance(poly, MultiPolygon)
False
```

This came to my attention when attempting to simplify an existing stored `MultiPolygon` value. Below is my model:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180)
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

The process I used to simplify the `MultiPolygon` is below. The last line causes the exception to be raised:

```sh
>>> from my_app.models import Location
>>> location = Location.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> geom = location.mpoly
>>> simplified_geom = geom.simplify(0.0002)
>>> location.mpoly = simplified_geom
```

If I use the `Polygon` to create a `MultiPolygon`, it works fine:

```sh
>>> multi = MultiPolygon([simplified_geom,])
>>> location.mpoly = multi
```

**Is the note in the tutorial misleading or am I doing something wrong?**

---

EDIT: Further tests on the geometries.

The original `MultiPolygon` straight from the model field:

```sh
>>> geom = Location.mpoly
>>> type(geom)
<class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.collections.MultiPolygon'>
>>> geom.geom_type
'MultiPolygon'
>>> geom.valid
True
>>> geom.srid
4326
```

Applying the `simplify()` method:

```sh
>>> simplified_geom = geom.simplify(0.0002)
>>> type(simplified_geom)
<class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.polygon.Polygon'>
>>> simplified_geom.geom_type
'Polygon'
>>> simplified_geom.valid
True
>>> simplified_geom.srid
4326
```

Creating a `MultiPolygon` from the simplified geometry:

```sh
>>> multi = MultiPolygon([simplified_geom,])
>>> type(multi)
<class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.collections.MultiPolygon'>
>>> multi.geom_type
'MultiPolygon'
>>> multi.valid
True
>>> multi.srid
>>> print(multi.srs)
None
```

Note that the above `MultiPolygon` has no SRID. I thought that might have been the reason is was being accepted. I created one with the `srid=4326` argument but it too was accepted by the field.

Here's a really basic example of the problem:

```sh
>>> # This works
>>> location.mpoly = MultiPolygon()
>>> # This doesn't
>>> location.mpoly = Polygon()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mattrowbum/.virtualenvs/musicteacher/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/proxy.py", line 75, in __set__
    instance.__class__.__name__, gtype, type(value)))
TypeError: Cannot set Location SpatialProxy (MULTIPOLYGON) with value of type: <class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.polygon.Polygon'>
```

Comment: Can you please share the `Model` and more specifically the `MultiPolygonField` creation? Do you use `geography=True` option in there?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis - I've updated the question with the model declaration and the process. I've since looked into the source of the [LayerMapping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/layermapping/#django.contrib.gis.utils.LayerMapping) utility, and in these circumstances it constructs a multi-geometry if a single geometry is provided.

Comment: Yes I have seen this before, the issue is with the `geography=True` setting and the Polygon you are passing in the field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451675/cannot-set-model-name-spatialproxy-polygon-with-value-of-type-class-django

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

Although the [`MultiPolygon` code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0b655a4bf81f640d3e664f398e635943d4fb7812/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py#L101) seems to allow a `Polygon` to b stored as `MultiPolygon` object:

> ```
> class MultiPolygon(GeometryCollection):
>     _allowed = Polygon
>     _typeid = 6
> ```

the issue you are presenting rises as you describe it.

I have tried some workarounds and the only one that I am somewhat satisfied with is to refactor your `geom` field into a generic [`GeometryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geometryfield) that can store any type of geometry.

Another option without touching your model would be to convert each `Polygon` to a `MultiPolygon` before inserting it to the field:

```
p = Polygon()
location.mpoly = MultiPolygon(p)
```

***Seems to me that this is worthy of an issue with either a Tutorial update request, or a code fix.***

---

*Leaving the previous state of the answer here for comment continuity:*

[The issue is with the `geography=True` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451675/cannot-set-model-name-spatialproxy-polygon-with-value-of-type-class-django) and not with the field, because the `MultiPolygonField` does accept a `Polygon` as well as a `MultiPolygon`:

> **The geography type provides native support for spatial features represented with geographic coordinates (e.g., WGS84 longitude/latitude).** Unlike the plane used by a geometry type, the geography type uses a spherical representation of its data. Distance and measurement operations performed on a geography column automatically employ great circle arc calculations and return linear units. In other words, when ST_Distance is called on two geographies, a value in meters is returned (as opposed to degrees if called on a geometry column in WGS84).

Since you set the field to expect a geography type object, then if you try to pass a non-geography representation of a Polygon, you will get the error in question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, but I'm still a bit confused. All I'm doing is using the [simplify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.simplify) method to create a new `GEOSGeometry` from the original field value. The SRID of the created Polygon is still 4326. Is there anything else I can check that would indicate a non-geography Polygon?

Comment: I've updated the question with a quick example showing that if I convert the new `Polygon` into a `MultiPolygon`, it is accepted.

Comment: @MattRowbum can you check if the failing geometry is still a `Polygon` and that it is `valid` after the `simplify`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnMoutafis - yes, I can confirm that it is both a `Polygon` and valid. I've added more test results to the end of the question. It will even accept a blank `MultiPolygon`, but raises an exception with a blank `Polygon`.

Comment: @MattRowbum I tried your issue and couldn't find a satisfying solution :/. Maybe this is a bug in Django and an issue should be probably raised. I made an update with a workaround and my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As other guys, I had to face this recurrent error raised by django geos:

```
django Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
```

I saw several answers all over the web, but none of them was satisfying my request. The easiest, and probably the most straightforward was to "re-cast" a polygon into a multipolygon just before updating the DB, as below:

```
                this_geom = GEOSGeometry(wkt_w.write(my_multipolygon_which_is_a_polygon))
                # detect if it is a polygon
                if this_geom and isinstance(this_geom, Polygon):
                    # if yes, then cast it into a multipolygon
                    this_geom = MultiPolygon(this_geom)

                my_map, created = my_obj.objects.update_or_create(

                    ...

                defaults={
                    'map': this_geom
                    }
                )
```